# How can my html not read my js

Tags: javascript, html

This is just 1 html file but whenever I seperate them I have

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="registerform" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
First name:<br>
<label>
    <input type="text" required="required" name="getfirstname">
</label><br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" required="required" name="lastname"><br>
Email address:<br>
<input type="email" required="required" name="email"><br>
Password:<br>
<input type="password" required="required" name="password"><br>
Password2:<br>
<input type="password" required="required" name="password2"><br>
<input type="submit"  value="Submit">
</form>
```

and

```
window.validateForm=function() {

alert(document.forms["registerform"]);
var x = document.forms["registerform"]["password"].value;
var y = document.forms["registerform"]["password2"].value;
if (y != x){
    alert("The passwords do not match. Please try again!");
    return false;
}
return true;
}</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I got the full js just under my form, it does execute the script.

But when I put

```
<script>"/JS/Form.js"</script>
```

it doesn't work...

Any idea?

Comment: can you post the project structure? I think that your file .js isn't loaded sucsesfully

Comment: Please post some snippets of actual code

Comment: check your script path. Check browser console also.

Comment: Please post what you have done. At least an example where it does not work.

Comment: Either (1) Something is different with the code you put in the external script (2) Your URL is wrong (3) Your server is denying permission or throwing some other error. There's no way to tell from your question.

Comment: did you try it off and back on again ?

Comment: Try removing the leading `/` in the src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that you want to load your javascript file from a relative path (relative to your html page) rather than an absolute path. Absolute paths start with a / (slash).

Try

```
<script src="js/script1.js"></script>
```

To debug it right click your page and click on the javascript src value. A page with the file content gets shown. It will tell you if the src does not point to an actual file available on your server.